# Linq Generic Method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

How I make a generic Update method using linq for tables with diferent nomenclature. PS I only need to Update two fields(floats both) but their names vary from one table to another, and the name of the id of the table also varies

Suppose I have these Tables in my DataContext:

```
Person   {ID(key), Name, X(float), Y(float)}
Vehicle  {Code(key), Model, Latitude(float), Longitude(float)}
Building {Name(key), Model, Latitude1(float), Longitude1(float)}
```

**the tables are fictional but represent my scenario as it is. I can not change the names of table fields, to achieve a standard nomenclature. (I do not make the database).*

I need to make a Generic Method in Linq. Something like this:

```
public void UdpateCoordinates(tableName, idOfTable, fieldLatitude, fieldLongitude)
{
  //And make a Update here of the fields (fieldLatitude, fieldLongitude).
  //Example person would be fields X and Y the ones to update.
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should ask a specific question instead of a "I need to.... Thanks."

Comment: Can you modify the C# classes that represent the tables to implement a common interface?

Comment: I cant not modify the classes, becouse other applications already use the bd. Thanks.

Comment: What does it have to do with LINQ? You don't update with LINQ, you **query** with LINQ.

Comment: ken2k sorry, my question is how to make a generic Update method using linq for tables with diferent nomenclature. PS I only need to Update two fields(floats both) but their names vary from one table to another, and the name of the id of the table also varies. Thanks

Comment: jimmy_keen something like this: var person = context.Person.Where(p=>p.ID == id); p.X = fieldLatitude; context.SubmitChanges(); this is not Linq?

Comment: I agree with @dtb, you could implement an interface. It wouldn't break the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an interface

```
public interface IPosition {
   public int ID {get ;}
   public Latitude {get; set;}
   public Longitude {get; set;}
}
```

Make your classes Vehicle, Building implement the interface.

Here is a possible version of the UdpateCoordinates method:

```
    public void UdpateCoordinates<T>(IEnumerable<T> table, int ID, float latitude, float longitude ) where T: IPosition {
       var entity = table.Where(x.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
       if (entity != null){
           entity.Latitude = longitude ;
           entity.Longitude = longitude ;
       } 

       //Save the entity here
    }
```